# Tablesorter meta-data sort

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I successfully applied initioal sort and filter via meta data like this:

```
<th data-columnSelector="true" data-value="">FKRace</th>
<th data-columnSelector="false" data-value="">CodeLevel</th>
<th data-columnSelector="true" data-value="">CName</th>
<th data-columnSelector="true" data-value="40000">Votes</th>
```

Now i need one more option to sort columns via meta data someting like

```
data-columnSorter = "ASC"
```

I check option:

```
<table cellspacing="1" class="tablesorter {sortlist: [[0,0],[4,0]]}">
```

But like this is difficult because my tables are dynamic and i drag sorting option from database.
In fact i need to be able to sort via  name or id but OUTSIDE of main script config. Is this possible and how can i solve problem ?
Tnx in advance

Answer (score 0):

To change the sort prior to initializing tablesorter, use a data-attribute:

```
<table data-sortlist="[[0,0],[4,0]]">
```

In order to make the following method work, the [jQuery metadata](https://github.com/jquery-archive/jquery-metadata) plugin must be loaded.

```
<table class="tablesorter {sortlist: [[0,0],[4,0]]}">
```

Please be aware that the data-attribute method will only work on [this fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/). The metadata method will work on both the original and forked versions of tablesorter.

For more details, see the documentation for the [`sortList` option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#sortlist).

Comment: Tnx dude, i will do like that